# grep a string between two patterns multiple instances in a file?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm new to bash scripting and I need to make a script that will go through files of logs about jobs that ran and I need to extract certain values such as the memory used and then the memory requested to calculate the memory used.

To begin this I'm simply trying to get a grep command that will grep a value between two patterns in a file, which will be my starting point for this script.

The file looks something like this:

> 20200429:04/29/2020 04:25:32;S;1234567.vpbs3;user=xx group=xxxxxx=_xxx_xxx_xxxx jobname=xx_xxxxxx queue=xxx ctime=1588148732 qtime=1588148732 etime=1588148732 start=1588148732 exec_host=xxx2/1*8 exec_vnode=(xx2:mem=402653184kb:ncpus=8) Resource_List.mem=**393216mb** Resource_List.ncpus=8 Resource_List.nodect=1 Resource_List.place=free Resource_List.preempt_targets=NONE Resource_List.Qlist=xxxq Resource_List.select=1:mem=393216mb:ncpus=8 Resource_List.walltime=24:00:00 resource_assigned.mem=**402653184kb** resource_assigned.ncpus=8

The values in bold are what I need to extract. Its multiple jobs and dates, so the file goes on with multiple paragraphs like this of data with different dates and numbers.

From going through similar questions online, I've come up with:

```
egrep -Eo 'Resource_List.mem=.{1,50}' sampleoutput.txt | cut -d "=" -f 2-
```

and I get multple lines of this:

```
393216mb Resource_List.ncpus=8 Resource_List.nodec
```

and I'm stuck as to how to get only that '393216mb' as I've never really used grep or cut much. Any suggestions, even if its not using grep, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If they are all lines formatted like this, you could just feed the file through `cut -d' ' -f12,20`, which gives `Resource_List.mem=393216mb resource_assigned.mem=402653184kb`.

Comment: If you then want just the values, feed the file through: `cut -d' ' -f12,20 | sed 's/[^ ]\+=//g'`, which gives only the RHS values: `393216mb 402653184kb`

Comment: @Roadowl hmm when i run that with the example file i posted i get '20200429:04/29/2020 xx _xxx_xxx_xxxx xx_xxxxxx xxx 1588148732 1588148732 1588148732 1588148732 xxx2/1*8 8) 393216mb 8 1 free NONE xxxq 8 24:00:00 402653184kb 8' so its much closer getting just whats after the equals lol

Comment: You must feed the file through `cut -d' ' -f12,20 | sed 's/[^ ]\+=//g'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
grep -o -E 'Resource_List.mem=[^\ ]+|resource_assigned.mem=[^\ ]+'
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! is there any way to add to it to get the 1234567 in 1234567.vpbs3 ?

Comment: `grep -o -E 'Resource_List.mem=[^\ ]+|resource_assigned.mem=[^\ ]+|[0-9]+\.vpbs3'` works, but I have a feeling vpbs3 is a machine name or a node name that can vary, right?

Comment: It's actually the job id! but yes it varies

Comment: If this is the answer that helped you, would you please upvote it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Very close! `.` is a wildcard, you want to match numbers.

```
egrep -Eo 'Resource_List.mem=[0-9]*..' sampleoutput.txt
```